# completely positive and contractive order zero maps

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be  $C^*$-algebras such that $A$ is unital, and let $\phi: A\rightarrow B$ be a c.p.c. order zero map. Then $\phi$ is a $*$-homomorphism if and only if $\phi(1_A)$ is a projection.

Since $\phi$ is a c.p.c. order zero map, we know that $\phi(ab)\phi(1_A)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$ for all $a,b \in A$. If $\phi$ is a $*$-homomorphism, it is obvious that $\phi(1_A)$ is a projection. How to prove the the other direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the identity $\phi(ab)\phi(1_A)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$, it suffices to show that $\phi(a)\phi(1_A)=\phi(a)$ for all $a$. Since positive elements span $A$, it suffices to show this for $a\geq 0$.

First, note that $\phi(1_A)$ commutes with $\phi(A)$.  Using the $C^*$-identity, the fact that $\phi(1_A)$ is a projection, and the identity $\phi(ab)\phi(1_A)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\|\phi(a)\phi(1_A)-\phi(a)\|^2&=\|(\phi(a)\phi(1_A)-\phi(a))(\phi(a)\phi(1_A)-\phi(a))\|\\
&=\|\phi(a)\phi(1_A)\phi(a)\phi(1_A)-\phi(a)\phi(1_A)\phi(a)-\phi(a)^2\phi(1_A)+\phi(a)^2\|\\
&=\|\phi(a)^2-\phi(a)^2\phi(1_A)\|\\
&=\|\phi(a^2)\phi(1_A)-\phi(a^2)\phi(1_A)\|\\
&=0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you  so much. I did not think of this method. I tried to prove  $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$ from $(\phi(ab)-\phi(a)\phi(b))\phi(1_A)=0$.

Comment: That could potentially work, but I feel like that would lead to several complications.

Comment: May I know your research interest? Would you mind recommending some questions about your research topic and some reference book? Thanks